# Load iframe and script synchronously

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have `<iframe src="some source">` and `<script src="source.js"></script>`

I want to load `iframe` before `script`.

Simple consecutive insertion in html doesn't work (sometimes script is loaded earlier than iframe).

Also, catching `iframe.onload` and dynamically adding the script is not what I want, since `source.js` contains `document.write` and chrome blocks that from asynchronous scripts.

Comment: Do you have to use `document.write` in your script?

Comment: It is not my script. It is external script.

Answer (score -2):

<s>Add the `defer` attribute to your script, so it doesn't load until after the page loads:</s>

```
<iframe src="some source"> 
<script defer src="source.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** For anyone (like me) who didn't know why `defer` wouldn't work with a script containing `document.write()`, here's the explanation from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> Note: document.write in deferred or asynchronous scripts will be ignored, and you'll get a message like "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored" in the error console.

Comment: Will that work for scripts containing `document.write`, as per the OPs requirements?

Comment: No. document.write is also blocked.